# Application of Lagrange theorem with absolute value

Tags: derivatives, solution-verification, absolute-value

I have to solve an exercise using the Lagrange theorem but I have doubt.
From the theorem I know that, let  a continuous function in $[a,b]$ and differentiable in $(a,b)$ then:
$$\exists c\in(a,b): ,\, f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\,\,\,\,\, (*)$$
Now I need the equality with the absolute value. Can I say that if (*) holds then it holds also the following?
$$|f'(c)|=\left|\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}\right|$$

Comment: btw, is that called the Lagrange theorem rather than the mean value theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, $x = y$ implies $|x|=|y|$.